# Chromeエクステンションで動画をストックする機能を作りたい

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

JavaScriptでChromeエクステンションを開発しています。
Chromeエクステンションを開発するのは初めてで、先ほどドットインストールで全20回分を学習しました。サンプルもいくつか作り、だいたいの仕組みは分かっています。また、JavaScriptも初心者で、同じくドットインストールで学習した程度です。

動画版はてなブックマークのようなエクステンションを作ろうとしていて、動画ページを開いてボタンをクリックするとその動画ページがストック（ブックマーク）されて、popup.htmlにはストックされた動画のサムネイルが取得されて一覧表示され、いつでも動画を見られる、というエクステンションを作りたいのですが、実現方法が検索しても分かりません。

chrome.bookmarksを使えばいいのかと思いましたが、ブラウザのブックマークに追加するわけではないので違うかなと思いました。
サムネイルはembed.lyというAPIを使えばいいのかなと思っていますが、漠然としか分かりません。
ヒントになるような機能やサイトを教えていただければと思います。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

情報の保存には例えば、[chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) が使えます。

動画のサムネイルの提供のされ方は、各々の動画サイトによって違いますが、（例:[YouTubeのAPI](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails)）最近では多くのサイトが下記のようなタグで画像を提供していますので、ある程度は取得方法を共通化出来るかもしれません。

```
<meta property="og:image" content="...jpg">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="...jpg">
```

ページのキャプチャを取得するならば、[chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab) などが使えます。